# How to respond to OCSPRequest when using a self signed certificate?

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, openssl

I'm trying to create an https server using a self signed certificate, but it seems to fail because it requires a response to the `OCSPRequest` callback, which I have no idea what that should contain. The documentation (https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_event_ocsprequest) is not helpful at all in my case, especially this part:

> 3. Server extracts the OCSP URL from either the certificate or issuer and performs an OCSP request to the CA.

How do I extract the OCSP URL? Do I even need to do that? What/who is the CA? Certificate Authority? No idea, I guess that's me in this case because I created the certificate myself, correct? How do I proceed?

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const httpsServer = require("https").createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync("./key.pem"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("./cert.pem"),
});
const server = httpsServer.listen(9777);
server.on('OCSPRequest', (certificate, issuer, callback) => {
  let response = 'What goes in here?';
  callback(null, response);
});
```

All the examples that I found never mention it, for instance: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A self-signed certificate cannot be revoked, since the issuer of the certificate is the certificate itself. No revocation possible means no OCSP response. The expected behavior based on the documentation you've linked to is thus:

> Alternatively, callback(null, null) may be called, indicating that there was no OCSP response.